# Compilation error on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I'm trying to install the driver of the probe IPEH-00202242179, I downloaded an installation file with the following commands:

```
$ cd peak-linux-driver-7.9
$ make clean
$ make 
$ su -c "make install"
```

But the problem is when I do `make` I get the following error message:

> make [1]: [PCAN-settings] Error 1 *

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You should definitively edit your question and write everything in english.

Comment: I edited the Q and put it into English.

Comment: We'd need to see more of the output around that error message to help further.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your issue in this forum post about peak titled: [PEAK 7.8 Drivers - Debian](http://www.peak-system.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=864). You need to make sure that the Linux Kernel source is installed, so that you can compile this driver.

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers
```